# php implode doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, simplexml, implode

I made some SimpleXMLObject and converted it into an array and implode them
but the result is not imploded string but the first element of array alone.

funnier thing is it's working as expected in my local server whose version is 5.4.4
but that malfunction is happening in my live server whose php version is 5.3.13
this is what my implode looks like

```
$im_data = implode( '#', (array)$sync->datas->data);
```

the target array is as follows :

```
[datas] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => AAzdfAA
                [1] => BBdBB
                [2] => BBDD
                [3] => CCCCzsdfC
            )

    )
```

but the result is NOT AAzdfAA#BBdBB#BBDD#CCCCzsdfC but only AAzdfAA in my live server.
well in my local server it works as expected : AAzdfAA#BBdBB#BBDD#CCCCzsdfC

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Try doing a print_r() or var_dump() of the array to check if you are getting all the desired values in the array. May be why not update your question with a sample from there as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue on my end. And used this workaround to get the desire output:

```
<?php

$xml = "<xml>
            <datas>
                <data>AAzdfAA</data>
                <data>BBdBB</data>
                <data>BBDD</data>
                <data>CCCCzsdfC</data>
            </datas>
        </xml>";

$sync = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$data = (array)$sync->datas;

$im_data = implode( '#', $data['data']);

echo $im_data; //Outputs: AAzdfAA#BBdBB#BBDD#CCCCzsdfC
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it does the trick! thanks , and i don't know why  php behaves like that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is in how the SimpleXML objects get converted to other types: first in your explicit request to turn the object into an array, and secondly to take the array of objects that will (hopefully) return and them into strings that can be handled by `implode`.

You'll need to test the different cases, but it sounds like the behaviour of casting to array was changed in PHP 5.4. To be sure it does the right thing, loop over the elements manually rather than relying on the cast.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for converting XML Object to Array

```
<?php
function xml2array ( $xmlObject, $out = array () )
{
        foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
            $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;

        return $out;
}

$xml_arr=xml2array($xml_obj);

$im_data = implode( '#',$xml_arr);


?>
```

i hope it will give you expected output